# .NetCore 2.2 Web Api with windows authentication returns 401 from other domains

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, windows-authentication

Before I write this I spent a lot of time searching and trying a lot of things, but nothing worked. It's a .NetCore 2.2 Web Api and I'm consuming it from Angular 8 application.

1. If I call the web api from the same domain it works fine.
2. If I call the web api from other domain (or localhost) it returns 401 (Unauthorized).
3. If I call the web api from other domain (or localhost) with windows authentication disabled - it works fine (so CORS is properly configured).

In my ***launchSettings.json*** I have:

```
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

In my ***web.config*** i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" />
      <security>
        <authentication>
           <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
           <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In ***IIS*** i have Windowsauthentication enabled and Anonymousauthentication disabled.

In my ***Startup.cs*** I have:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder =>
            {
               builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials();
            });
        });

        services.AddMvc()
        .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
     }
```

and

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

What I'm missing? Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the request to the web API is initiated from the browser?

A 401 response is expected when using Windows Authentication. Then the client is expected to resend the request with the correct credentials.

Browsers can be configured to automatically send the credentials of the currently logged on user. IE and Chrome will do this if the site is in the Trusted Sites list in Internet Options. Firefox has its own `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris` setting.

So either:

1. The browser doesn't trust the site so it is not automatically sending credentials, or
2. The domain of your server does not trust the domain of the user, so even if the browser sends the credentials of the current user, they will be rejected with a second 401 response.

Comment: The web api is called from angular application. Both are on trusted sites and they are subdomais of the same domain. It opens the dialog asking for credentials.

Comment: Do you see the Authorization header sent? (note that the Chrome dev tools don't show this header even if it is sent but IE will - or use Fiddler)

Comment: You can read about the request flow for Windows Authentication [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/IIS-Support-Blog/Windows-Authentication-HTTP-Request-Flow-in-IIS/ba-p/324645). It might help understand what's supposed to happen.

Comment: Thanks for that info but it does not solve the problem. My question was and is, how can I make it work ?

Comment: I know :) That's why I asked if are you seeing the Authorization header being sent. It won't work if that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of the middleware might be all you need to fix this issue--see this [Microsoft source on Middleware Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order) which specifies that `UseCors()` should be added before `UseAuthentication()`.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

This answer may be too late to help the OP, but maybe it will help someone later.